# Split on first occurrence of character

Tags: javascript

I've checkhours string like shown below and I want to split by first occurrence of '-' character, however, I'm not getting the correct result as shown in below code. Also, I want to make an array like 11:30 AM – 4:00 PM 1st part and 5:00 PM – 12:00 AM 2nd part?

```
          console.log("checkHours", checkHours);
          let [start, end] = checkHours.split(' – ');

          current log:
          checkHours 11:30 AM – 4:00 PM, 5:00 PM – 12:00 AM
          start, end 11:30 AM 4:00 PM, 5:00 PM
```

That is, I want the result to be like-> first element in array should be 11:30 AM – 4:00 PM and second element in array 5:00 PM – 12:00 AM. Then I can split on first element of array 11:30 AM – 4:00 PM by '-' which gives result start = 11:30 AM and end = 4:00 PM.

Comment: Don't you want to split on the comma instead? What should your output look like?

Comment: `checkHours.split(', ').map(s => s.split(' – '))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option #1
join back the other splitted elements:

```js
checkHours = "11:30 AM – 4:00 PM, 5:00 PM – 12:00 AM";
console.log("checkHours", checkHours);
let [start, ...end] = checkHours.split(' – ');
end = end.join(" - ");
console.log(start);
console.log(end);
```

Option #2:
Don't use split

```js
checkHours = "11:30 AM – 4:00 PM, 5:00 PM – 12:00 AM";
console.log("checkHours", checkHours);
let start, end;
if (checkHours.indexOf(" – ") > -1) {
  [start, end] = [checkHours.slice(0, checkHours.indexOf(" – ")), checkHours.slice(checkHours.indexOf(" – ") + 3)];
}
console.log(start);
console.log(end);
```

Comment: So start by split using `, ` (and **not** ` - `), and once you have this value, you can split the dash.

Comment: result is not correct. start is right but end should be only 4:00 PM. Then in second part, start (5:00 PM) and end (12:00 AM)

Comment: This is an example. You can use this code in order to understand how split of strings work, and adjust it to your needs.